# Error in match.arg(opt_crit) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Tags: r, forecast

Error in match.arg(opt_crit) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

occurs when trying to run my script in r.

I have tried to find the solution for it, but it seems to be pretty specific, and little help for me.

My dataset contains 3936 obs of 7 variables.

environment, skill, volume, datetime, year, month, day

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   3696 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ environment: chr  "b2b" "b2b" "b2b" "b2b" ...
 $ skill      : chr  "BO Bedrift" "BO Bedrift" "BO Bedrift" "BO Bedrift" ...
 $ year       : num  2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 ...
 $ month      : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ day        : num  2 9 16 23 30 6 13 20 27 6 ...
 $ volume     : num  360 312 305 222 113 ...
 $ datetime   : Date, format: "2017-01-02" "2017-01-09" "2017-01-16" "2017-01-23" ...
```

but when trying to run

```
volume_ets <- volume_tsbl %>% ETS(volume)
```

this message shows in the console

```
Error in match.arg(opt_crit) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

I tried somewhat of a shortcut, but nothing helped,

```
volume_tsbl$volume <- as.numeric(as.character(volume_tsbl$volume))
```

Tried to run

```
volume_ets <- volume_tsbl %>% ETS(volume)
```

this message shows in the console

```
Error in match.arg(opt_crit) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

I tried somewhat of a shortcut, but nothing helped,

```
volume_tsbl$volume <- as.numeric(as.character(volume_tsbl$volume))

volume_ets <- volume_tsbl %>% ETS(volume)
```

my tsibble looks like this;

```
volume_tsbl <- volume %>¤ as_tsibble(key = c(skill, environment), index = c(datetime), regular = TRUE )
```

Expected the code to run, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of an interface change made in late 2018. The change was to make model functions (such as `ETS()`) create model definitions, rather than fitted models. Essentially, `ETS()` no longer accepts data as an input, and the specification for the ETS model would become `ETS(volume)`.

The equivalent code in the current version of fable is:

```
volume_ets <- volume_tsbl %>% model(ETS(volume))
```

Where the `model()` function is used to train one or more model definitions (`ETS(volume)` in this case) to a given dataset.

You can refer to the pkgdown site for fable to see more details: http://fable.tidyverts.org/
In particular, the `ETS()` function is documented here: http://fable.tidyverts.org/reference/ETS.html